# Use speech recognition from C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am trying to write a program that supports speech recognition via a custom (specialised) grammar. However, the SpeechRecognized event never fires, and the speech recognition applet acts as if the grammar didn't exist.

Here are my precise steps. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

1. Open Control Panel, search for "speech", then click on "Start speech recognition".
2. Open Visual C#, create a new Windows Forms project
3. Copy and paste the code from [the first answer on this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227140/c-speech-recognition-is-this-what-the-user-said) into the project.
4. Add the necessary reference to System.Speech.
5. Run the program, with the speech recognition applet still running.
6. Say "Start listening".
7. Say a number between 1 and 100.

The label's text never changes from its default value ("label1"), so it seems that rec_SpeechRecognized() is never called, i.e. the SpeechRecognized event never fires. If I say a number that sounds somewhat similar to the name of an open window or a program in my start menu, it'll ask me if that is what I meant. It appears to be completely agnostic of the custom grammar I just defined.

I tried lots of examples I found on the web, which are all pretty much equivalent to the example in that answer I linked to, only with different grammar. I get the same result for all of them, so I assume I must be doing something else wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you put a break point on the recognizer callback to see if it does get called/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the lack of answers I suspect it works for everyone else but not for me. Thus, looks like the answer is "it's not possible".

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't linked the Form1 load event to the `Form1_Load` routine in the designer.  I followed your steps exactly, and had the same results; see if you can get a breakpoint anywhere in `Form1_Load`.

Once I edited the designer to make sure that `Form1_Load` actually got called, it ran fine.

Comment: Yes, I did link the event. Of course I tried setting a breakpoint; the code in Form1_Load does run. You say "it ran fine" - did you try the speech recognition and did it actually recognise the numbers for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you read other posts in the same thread, there is one which says you should add the numbers as one, two, etc. rather than 1, 2...