# C# System.Speech notfound!

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

im trying to use Speech Recognition related to this: 
[C# Speech Recognition - Is this what the user said?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227140/c-speech-recognition-is-this-what-the-user-said)

but the system cant find its assemblies.

Comment: Are you using Framework 3.5 or later? Because I don't think you can find it in previous frameworks...

Comment: yes i use .net 4 , also i know there were in version 3 also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you [have a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx) to System.Speech.Recognition in your project.

Also, this is available only on .NET 3.0 and above.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was it the reference, or did you get an "aha" moment and find it elsewhere?

Answer (score 10):

you have to add System.Speech.Recognition to your project.

In .Net 3.0 and Above

[image]

Answer (score 3):

System.Speech is available in .Net 3.0 and later. The MSDN page for the 3.0 version is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition(v=VS.85).aspx. The recognizer engines are only available by default in Windows Vista and Windows 7. Did you get a runtime exception? What was it?

You might want to look over the answer in [What is the best option for transcribing speech-to-text in a asp.net web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730318/what-is-the-best-option-for-transcribing-speech-to-text-in-a-asp-net-web-app/4737003#4737003) for some more info.

To add some details to the version mentioned in the comments, one source is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Speech_Recognition which says:

> Speech recognition technology has been
>   used in some of Microsoft's products,
>   including Microsoft Dictation (a
>   research prototype that ran on Windows
>   9x). It was also included in Office
>   XP, Office 2003,[3] Microsoft Plus!
>   for Windows XP, Windows XP Tablet PC
>   Edition, and Windows Mobile (as
>   Microsoft Voice Command).[4] However,
>   prior to Windows Vista, speech
>   recognition was not mainstream. In
>   response, Windows Speech Recognition
>   was bundled with Windows Vista and
>   released in 2006, making the operating
>   system the first mainstream version of
>   Microsoft Windows to offer fully
>   integrated support for speech
>   recognition.

The following table used to be available at http://www.microsoft.com/speech/developers.aspx, under “.Net 3.x System.Speech”, then in the bottom right click on “Microsoft Speech Engines”. It is no longer there. I saved this image on my hard drive and still have it:

[image]

The footnotes for the table were:

1. Version 6.1 of the Microsoft Speech Recognition Engines are available to Independent Software Vendors (ISV) in a redistribution package that can be installed along with their own application. The package also includes the SAPI version 5.1 components for installation on Windows 2000. For more information on obtaining the redistribution package, email listen@microsoft.com.
2. Available in 4 languages: English (U.S.), Japanese, Chinese (Simplified), and Chinese (Traditional)
3. Microsoft Office 2003 includes version 6.1 of the Microsoft Speech Recognition Engine, available in four languages2. Office 2003 can be installed on Windows 2003 Server and the engines be used by other applications
4. Available in 8 languages: English (U.S.), English (U.K.), German (Germany), French (France), Spanish (Spain), Japanese, Chinese (Traditional) and Chinese (Simplified).
5. Microsoft Anna is a U.S. English voice, and is included in all Windows Vista Editions in all languages.
6. Microsoft Lili speaks Chinese and English. The Microsoft Lili TTS engine is included in all Chinese language versions of Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. Users of Windows Vista Ultimate, Windows Vista Business Enterprise and Windows Server 2008 can download either the Chinese (Simplified) or Chinese (Traditional) Multilingual User Interface Language Packs pack and the Microsoft Lili voice will be installed.

Comment: +1 for including "The recognizer engines are only available by default in Windows Vista and Windows 7"  That's a pretty important detail.  I wasn't aware of that and don't see it in the documentation, but I never looked that hard, either.  Can you link to that documentation?

Comment: Actually, no I can't link to official documentation. I stumbled through a bunch of documentation, blog posts, and articles. I summarized what I could in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-rec. There used to be a list with some of this on the microsoft.com/speech site, but it was recently updated and that list is gone. See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx#tab=desktop for something that might be helpful.

Comment: OK.  I did find posts in the meantime where people are getting System.Speech namespaces to work on Windows XP, including this one that says that it works in XMP but not Vista, so I'm not sure your answer is accurate, but I don't develop on XP any more, so I can't verify it myself... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/abc026b8-bdb9-4e8f-941c-ad4eb3ddb490/

Comment: My understanding is that Windows XP tablet edition came with a recognizer. Office 2003 also came with a recognizer. So, (I think) if you have XP and Office 2003 installed these apps would work. However, they broke when run on XP machines without the recognizer.