# Disabling Main Speech Recognition in SAPI 5.3

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I'm coding a program which simply understands basic keywords such as 'left' or 'right'.
It works great, however in order to execute the program, first, i must start Windows Speech Recognition. While my program is running, this 'Windows Speech Recognition' is also processing the commands, and this sometimes shut my program or open a folder.
What i want to do is disable 'Windows Speech Recognition' and still be able to start my program properly.
My code is based on this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/video/Cc482921
Code: http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/0/1/b01ceff1-5ba9-41e2-ab4f-8b8f4c2f7467/SampleCoding-NativeCoding-ASR2.zip

Also, is there a way to work my program on a Windows editions(such as Windows XP or non-English Windows 7) which does not support speech recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an inproc instead of a shared recognizer if you only want your application to respond. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717071(v=VS.85).aspx may give you some guidance.

Windows XP Tablet edition included a recognizer. Office 2003 included a recognizer that many XP users have installed. I think later updates to XP included a recognizer, but I don't know for sure. I tried to outline the platforms and recognizers as I knew it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998963/90236 and in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5861145/90236