# Natural Language To SQl

Tags: mysql, sql, c#-4.0

is it possible to create a english to SQL app using Part of Speech Tagging. or else please suggest some efficient ways to do this app

Comment: Do you mean that you want to listen to speech and convert to an SQL statement ? if so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227140/c-sharp-speech-recognition-is-this-what-the-user-said

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but...

There is ["FCO-IM (Fully Communication Oriented Information Modeling)"](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/FCO-IM). It is relatively unknown, but it allows for "english to sql".

**For example**, you'd have code such as

```
There is a person with the name Saman;
Person with name Saman has last name Weerasinghe;

There is a Stackoverflow question with id 8062888;
Person with the name Saman asked Stackoverflow question with id 8062888;
```

Then you can define the relationships and multiplicity, and generate the tables for your data.